# Need help, VBA, need the combobox to avoid entering a specific values

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a list of data in a sheet from A1:A8 and i have a combobox1 in a userform. What i want is to avoid a user to input an invalid value in the combobox1 based on the lists of data in the sheet

Comment: Some simple research would lead you to a property in the ComboBox that disallows the user from adding new items. Then simply populate the ComboBox from A1:A8.

Answer (score -1):

Go to combobox properties and change `Style` from `0 - fmStyleDropDownCombo` to `2 - fmStyleDropDownList`

Comment: I tried it but sorry you didnt get my point...i want the combobox to input values that are not in the lists of the sheet ranging A1:A8

Answer (score -2):

i think this is what you are searching:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/combobox-beforeupdate-event-access

There you have a way to check the values with that you want, there is a example where you can replace it with your range of cells.

Edited (Nice point, i'll put the example here):

```
Private Sub Combobox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    For i = 1 to 8
        If(Cells(i, 1).Value == Me.Combobox.Value)
            Cancel = True 
            Me.Combobox.Undo 
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Cya.

Comment: The code you have provided will not run, and does not achieve what the OP has asked for. But kudos for attempting to fix a link-only answer.